# Insert data of 2 Hive external tables in new External table with additional column

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, external-tables

I have 2 external hive tables as follows. I have populated data in them from oracle using sqoop.

```
create external table transaction_usa
(
tran_id int,
acct_id int,
tran_date string,
amount double,
description string,
branch_code string,
tran_state string,
tran_city string,
speendby string,
tran_zip int
)
row format delimited
stored as textfile
location '/user/stg/bank_stg/tran_usa';

create external table transaction_canada
(
tran_id int,
acct_id int,
tran_date string,
amount double,
description string,
branch_code string,
tran_state string,
tran_city string,
speendby string,
tran_zip int
)
row format delimited
stored as textfile
location '/user/stg/bank_stg/tran_canada';
```

Now i want to merge above 2 tables data as it is in 1 external hive table with all same fields as in the above 2 tables but with 1 extra column to identify that which data is from which table. The new external table with additional column as `source_table`. The new external table is as follows.

```
create external table transaction_usa_canada
(
tran_id int,
acct_id int,
tran_date string,
amount double,
description string,
branch_code string,
tran_state string,
tran_city string,
speendby string,
tran_zip int,
source_table string
)
row format delimited
stored as textfile
location '/user/gds/bank_ds/tran_usa_canada';
```

how can I do it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do `SELECT` from each table and perform `UNION ALL` operation on these results and finally insert the result into your third table.

Below is the final hive query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE transaction_usa_canada
SELECT tran_id, acct_id, tran_date, amount, description, branch_code, tran_state, tran_city, speendby, tran_zip, 'transaction_usa' AS source_table FROM transaction_usa
UNION ALL
SELECT tran_id, acct_id, tran_date, amount, description, branch_code, tran_state, tran_city, speendby, tran_zip, 'transaction_canada' AS source_table FROM transaction_canada;
```

Hope this help you!!!

Comment: It worked ... can you also update as to how can I seperate the data using ,(comma)

Answer (score 0):

You can very well do it by `manual partitioning` as well.

```
CREATE TABLE transaction_new_table (
tran_id int,
acct_id int,
tran_date string,
amount double,
description string,
branch_code string,
tran_state string,
tran_city string,
speendby string,
tran_zip int
)
PARTITIONED BY (sourcetablename String)
```

Then run below command,

```
load data inpath 'hdfspath' into table transaction_new_table   partition(sourcetablename='1')
```

Comment: hi shankar... thanks... but I only need merging of data from 2 tables with last and new field as source_table. I am using

insert into new_table select columns from ext_table1, source_table_value. But its giving me an error

Comment: This will basically help you in faster retrieval of data . well in that case you also do a Union All.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the INSERT INTO Clause of Hive

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table transaction_usa_canada 
SELECT tran_id, acct_id, tran_date, ...'transaction_usa' FROM transaction_usa;

INSERT INTO TABLE table transaction_usa_canada 
SELECT tran_id, acct_id, tran_date, ...'transaction_canada' FROM transaction_canada;
```